# Selecting max percentage from the column for every subject

Tags: php, sql

I have table called `skills` in which different skills are stored for that particular user in %  so basically i want to select highest skills for that user from `skills` table and want to echo it in while loop for every user

```
user     |  skills  | 
userID   |    PHP   |
userName |    C++   |

 <?php 
$sql= "(SELECT *,max(skills) as higherPercentage
FROM skill LEFT JOIN user ON skill.userID=user.userID  ORDER BY  signup_date DESC ) ";    
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
?>
```

So If the user has Highest vale 99 compare to all the skills then it should be selected for him

Comment: `SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE ...`

Comment: Will it Select Highest Value For every userID i want it for while loop

Comment: i tried using max() but it echo the highest value from the table to all the users

Comment: Use a `GROUP BY` to get more than one result.

Comment: it is printing the highest value of the table to every user of the db

Answer (score 0):

Store values in like 1,0.5,6 not like 100%,10%
and then use

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name group by (user)
```

Comment: it is printing the highest value of the table to every user of the db

Comment: Thanks I have Updated it